# How do I make my table view less laggy in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My objective is to simply display a unique image and label for each row in my table view. This is currently where I'm at:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath )-> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0)) {
            let data = DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell.Static.data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.barName?.text = data.namesArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

  return cell
}
```

Contents of CellDataDisplayInformation:

```
struct CellDataDisplayInformation {
    var namesArray : [String?] = []
    var pictureArray : [UIImage?] = []

    init(){
        for index in 0...21 {
            var data = BarDetails(index: index)
            if data.barName != nil && data.barImage != nil {

                namesArray.append(data.barName!)
                pictureArray.append(data.barImage!)


            }
        }

    }

  }
```

`data  = CellDataDisplayInformation()` holds arrays of [Strings?] and [UIImages?] to be displayed in each respective cell. With this method the UI initially loads with all the correct information in each cell. However when I scroll down to the unseen cells, the labels in each cell shuffle for 2 seconds and then move to their correct spots.

If I don't use "dispatch" and just do:

```
 let data = CellDataDisplayInformation()
 cell.barName?.text = data.namesArray[indexPath.row]
```

All the labels for each cell remain constant and don't shuffle but the view lags as I scroll over each new cell.

So in conclusion how do I avoid shuffling and lagging when displaying data in table cells?

My DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell class:

```
  class DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: Properties

    struct Static  {
    static var data = CellDataDisplayInformation()
    }

@IBOutlet weak var barName: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.barName.text = nil
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.barName.text = nil
    super.prepareForReuse()
  }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to determine what's may cause this. Post the implementation of CellDataDisplayInformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dispatch_async` calls result in `cell.barName?.text = data.namesArray[indexPath.row]` being executed AFTER you return the `cell` in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You shouldn't do this, because those cells may have already been re-used for some other row by the time you get the data.

Instead of setting the text on that particular `cell`, you need to ask the table to vend a cell for the index you've fetched data for. if that index is still on screen by the time you get your data, the tableView will give you the correct cell. otherwise, it returns nil.

Like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0)) {

        let data = CellDataDisplayInformation()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            //do it this way
            if let futureCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell {
                futureCell.barName?.text = data.namesArray[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nic. Just one last question if you may. How do I make futureCell conform to my custom cell class?

Comment: Yes my app builds just fine and the table scroll is smooth. However the names are still shuffling when I scroll down :(

Comment: ah. then you need to post all of the code for `DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell`

Comment: I just posted the contents of 'DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell'. Take a look. All I added was the '@IBOutlet'.

Comment: in your cell class, override `-prepareForReuse` and set `barName.text` to `nil`. Then, call `super.prepareForReuse`.

Comment: thanks again for the help. The -prepareForReuse deletes the information from the cells that aren't displayed on the screen. So If I scroll down fast enough the UI takes about 2 seconds to load completely. I updated my custom cell class above.

Comment: That sounds right. So that means `let data = CellDataDisplayInformation()` takes about 2 seconds to return. Do you know why it might take that long? Is it making a network request? What does `BarDetails` do?

Comment: I'm not using any networking code in my project.

BarDetails is a struct that pulls key values out of a hard coded library. This library contains 22 Dictionaries which result in 1714 lines of code. The init method in my Library struct appends all 22 Dictionaries together to make one big one. Each individual Dictionary has 7 nested Dictionaries. 

BarDetails struct has an init(index: index) so that I can pull information from each key from each library. 

CellDataDisplayInformation runs a for-loop over the property value I want to display in each cell.

Comment: If that is the case, then you don't really need to re-create all of that data every time a cell comes onscreen (causing this delay). You only need to do it once. try adding the `static` keyword, as in `static let data = CellDataDisplayInformation()`. This will only create your data store once (the first time), and it will continue to be in memory next time you create a cell.

Comment: Works just fine now! I couldn't just declare a static var outside of a struct so I embedded a new struct within my DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell class. I fixed my tableView method and DailyBarCellViewTableViewCell class above.

Comment: Great! Please upvote & accept this answer since it fixed the issue, Thanks @JoeH!